# d3.js pie chart Invalid value for <path> attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am begginer to d3.js and getting errors, I customized the example for my needs but gettings these in the console.  Please help. Thank you in Advance.

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M-1.8369701987210297e-14,-100A100,100 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA60,60 0 1,0 -1.1021821192326178e-14,-60Z"a @ d3.v3.min.js:1
d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNA100,100 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA60,60 0 1,0 NaN,NaNZ"
```

```js
 var getData = function () {
  var size = 3;
  var data =[];
  var text = "";

  data=[
   {
    label:"Saved",
    value:200,
   },{
    label:"Ordered",
    value:1255,
   },{
    label:"Shipped",
    value:760,
   },{
    label:"Backordered",
    value:150,
   },
   {
    label:"Cancelled",
    value:250,
   },
  ];
  d3.select("#data").html(text);
  return data;
 };


 console.log(getData());

 var chart = donut(250,200,16,40)
  .$el(d3.select("#chart"))
  .data(getData())
  .render();
 d3.select("#refresh").on("click", function () {
  chart.data(getData()).render();
 });


 function donut(width,height,label_font_size,value_font_size) {
  // Default settings
  var $el = d3.select("body")
  var data = {};
  // var showTitle = true;
  var width = width,
   height = height,
   radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  //var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius);
  var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius + 20);

  var currentVal;
  var color = d3.scale.category20();
  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
   .sort(null)
   .value(function (d) {
    console.log(d);
    return d.value.value;
   });

  var svg, g, arc;


  var object = {};

  // Method for render/refresh graph
  object.render = function () {
   if (!svg) {
    arc = d3.svg.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius)
     .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 2.5));

    svg = $el.append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
     .data(pie(d3.entries(data)))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
     // Attach current value to g so that we can use it for animation
     .each(function (d) {
      //this._current = d;
     })
     .attr("d", arc)
     .style("fill", function (d,i) {
      return color(i);
     });

    /*g.append("text")
     .attr("transform", function (d,i) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d,i) + ")";
     })

     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .style("text-anchor", "middle");
    g.select("text").text(function (d) {
     //return d.data.key;
    });
    */

    svg.append("text")
     .datum(data)
     .attr("x", 0)
     .attr("y", 0)
     .attr("class", "text-tooltip")
     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("font-weight", "bold")
     .style("font-size", radius / 2.5 + "px");

    g.on("mouseover", function (obj) {


     var tooltipText=svg.select("text.text-tooltip");
      tooltipText.attr("fill", function (d,i) {
       return color(i);
      });

     tooltipText.append("tspan")
        .attr("dy", -15)
        .attr("x",0)
     .attr("class", "text-tooltip-label")
     .style("font-size", label_font_size + "px")
        .text(function(d) {return d[obj.data.key].label;});

        tooltipText.append("tspan")
     .attr("dy", ".9em") // offest by 1.2 em
        .attr("x",0)
     .attr("class", "text-tooltip-value")
     .style("font-size", value_font_size + "px")
        .text(function(d) {return d[obj.data.key].value;});
      d3.select(this)
               .attr("stroke","white")
               .transition()
               .duration(1000)
               .attr("d", arcOver)
               .attr("stroke-width",6);


    });

    g.on("mouseout", function (obj) {
     svg.select("text.text-tooltip").text("");
      d3.select(this).transition()
               .attr("d", arc)
               .attr("stroke","none");
    });

   } else {
    g.data(pie(d3.entries(data))).exit().remove();

    g.select("path")
     .transition().duration(200)
     .attrTween("d", function (a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return function (t) {
       return arc(i(t));
      };
     });


    g.select("text")
     .attr("transform", function (d,i) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d,i) + ")";
     });

    svg.select("text.text-tooltip").datum(data);
   }
   return object;
  };

  // Getter and setter methods
  object.data = function (value) {
   if (!arguments.length) return data;
   data = value;
   return object;
  };

  object.$el = function (value) {
   if (!arguments.length) return $el;
   $el = value;
   return object;
  };

  object.width = function (value) {
   if (!arguments.length) return width;
   width = value;
   radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
   return object;
  };

  object.height = function (value) {
   if (!arguments.length) return height;
   height = value;
   radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
   return object;
  };

  return object;
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: The code above works.  Is this the example you are customizing?  How did you change it?

Comment: yes, code is working, but on chrome console I am getting errors. Invalid value for <path> attribute .... That was example with static graph and labels on it. I added animation on hover.